# Django i18n in production

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, django-i18n

I gotta bilingual project. It works properly in local development, but when I deploy it on heroku, it won't read the locale folder whereas it works on development
Is there any solution?
Vscode tells that .mo and .po are included

Comment: Include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. As everyone knows in order to have a bilingual project you need to have a package called `gettext` on your linux. I had dockerized my project but I hadn't included `gettext` in my dockerfile, and so after I included `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install gettext`, my problem was fixed.

This is my dockerfile currently:

```
FROM python:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install gettext -y

bluh ...
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).